# Cannot get out of while(true) - RealConnection#290 - squid3 - 407

Tags: okhttp

I have a problem with OkHttp-3.4.1 when using it with squid3 as proxy.
When I test my client with incorrect proxy credentials(proxy returns 407), I get into while(true){} loop - [RealConnection](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/158692870d5a5cf1fdf42bd62a18ffa699d7e0b3/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection.java#L347) which I cannot get out from.

So client is hanging forever.
How can I solve this?
Please, advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example which helped me to solve issue is at [okHttp repo](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Authenticate.java). The only change - replacing "Authorization" header with "Proxy-Authorization".